# I want to seperate the PHP JSON string in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I have a problem with separating the json array result. When I alert the json result in jquery it returns me the following array.

```
{"productid":"17","product_quantity":"2"}{"productid":"9","product_quantity":"1"}
```

Now I want to separate every value in a different variable.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: That's not valid json.

Comment: I reformatted to pass json validity tests [here](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=e171370201bcbc48a54efc45aedf96ec)

Comment: This question makes no sense at all. You should explain what you mean by each value in a different variable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It might be that your server returns a string that is not valid JSON. A valid example would be:

```
[{"productid":"17","product_quantity":"2"},{"productid":"9","product_quantity":"1"}]
```

How are you creating the json? Since you tagged PHP, the correct way (if you have an array) is like this, and it will return valid JSON, that you JS can handle:

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

that is not a valid json string. 
first, you can convert the input to json string.
then, you can use JSON.parse to get the js array.

e.g.

first you need to do this:

```
input = '[{"productid":"17","product_quantity":"2"},{"productid":"9","product_quantity":"1"}]'
```

then:

```
input_array = JSON.parse(input)
```

Answer (score -1):

The json you gave is misformed. I assume that's a typo.

Use JSON.parse to convert to a javascript object.

```
var jsonString = [{"productid":"17","product_quantity":"2"}, {"productid":"9","product_quantity":"1"}];
var data = JSON.parse(jsonString);
console.log(data[1].productid);  // 9
```

But I do not know what you mean by."Now I want to separate every value in different variable."

Why?
 Anyways you could do this. Though I do say dont. But you asked.

```
data.forEach(function(item){
    window["productid"+item.productid] = item.product_quantity;
});
```

will give you 2 vars in global scope

```
console.log(productid17); // "2"
console.log(productid9); // "1"
```